Not able to add box-shadow to content inside a tab
applying box shadow the the content of any tab does not show due to inner css of overflow hidden and width 100%, adding margin reduced the size of the content which looks mis-align compared to tab icons
Reproduction
StackBlitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rs9pc4?file=src%2Fstyles.scss
I tried to apply box-shadow using regular CSS syntax, and expected to have box-shadow around my div
image showing css applied and box-shadow not visible
code:
HTML
<mat-tab-group>
<mat-tab>
<div class="accordion-table-wrapper>.....</div>
</mat-tab>
<mat-tab-group>CSS

.accordion-table-wrapper{
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px red;
  border-radius: 12px;
}


I imagine you can always use (in your styles.sccs)
.mat-mdc-tab-body-wrapper{
box-shadow: 0 5px 5px silver;
border-radius:0 0 5px 5px;
padding:5px;
}
If you want all yours tab the same shadow or use some like
<mat-tab-group #tab [class]="'custom-'+tab.selectedIndex">
  ...
</mat-tab-group>

And
.custom-0 .mat-mdc-tab-body-wrapper{
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px silver;
  border-radius:0 0 5px 5px;
  padding:5px;
}
.custom-1 .mat-mdc-tab-body-wrapper{
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px red;
  border-radius:0 0 5px 5px;
  padding:5px;
}
.custom-2 .mat-mdc-tab-body-wrapper{
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px blue;
  border-radius:0 0 5px 5px;
  padding:5px;
}

Your forked stackblitz
